# Transform text to fields python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file where each line contain information like:

```
a: send value b: XYZ
```

How can I transform this to have a dictionary for each line:

```
{'a': 'send value', 'b': 'XYZ'}
```

What I have done before but I have some problems with text :

```
from parse import parse
import sys
with open("txt.txt") as fi:
    line = fi.readline()
    result = list(parse('{}: {} {}: {}', line))
    print({i:j for i,j in zip(result[::2], result[1::2])})
```

AND my result is :
    {'a': 'send', 'value b': 'XYZ'}

What is the the best way to handle text content

Comment: are a and b in the same line?

Comment: yes, they are in the same line

Comment: HI, and welcome to StackOverflow. Rather than asking us to write code for you, could you make your best guess at code and show us what's going wrong? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: Did you just copy an answer into your question as your “own” attempt?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from parse import parse
import sys


with open("txt.txt") as fi:
    line = fi.readline()
    result = list(parse('{}: {} {}: {}', line))
    print({i:j for i,j in zip(result[::2], result[1::2])})
```

Output:

```
{'a': 'text', 'b': 'text'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some code snippet so that we can start but for variety I have added a boilerplate code where I have made an assumption that there is one string in each line

```
a : text 
b: text
```

The code would be

```
mydict = {}
with open('ex.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        name, ip = line.split()
        if name not in mydict:
            mydict[name] = []
        mydict[name].append(ip.strip())
print(mydict)
```

Now you an do on your own if there exists multiple string on the same line